# Connection to SMTP server via PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have some problems with PHPMailer - it can't connect to SMTP server.
I use following settings:

```
$mail->Host = "mail.site.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 26;
$mail->Username = "test@site.com";
$mail->Password = "***";
```

And when i try to connect - i receive error "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host".
Also i try to set:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
OR
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

But error still presents.

In my email client (Thunderbird) with settings:

```
Server - mail.site.com
Port - 26
Secure Connection - STARTTLS
Username - test@site.com
```

I connect succesfully and can send/receive emails. Also via telnet mail.site.com 26 i succesfully connect.

Why with same settings i can't connect to server?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Are you sure you should be connecting to port 26? SMTP normally runs on port 25 (inbound), and you should normally send using tls on port 587.